# Very slow Django: Multiple "SHOW default_transaction_isolation" calls in log

Tags: django, postgresql, psycopg2

I am using Django 1.5.4 with PostgreSQL 9.2.4.-2 through psycopg2 2.5.1.

From some point of time I noticed that my Django site became extremely slow - it takes about 2-3 seconds to load small pages with only several lightweight queries.

Django-debug-toolbar says:

`241,70 ms (161 queries)` - query time

`time 2992ms` - total page load time

So, the queries should not be the problem... But that's not true! I've set up postgresql query logging and I got this:

```
[LOG ENTRY] 2013-09-18 11:17:05.148 MSK 10304 127.0.0.1(38834)LOG:  duration: 0.762 ms  statement: SELECT ...
[LOG ENTRY] 2013-09-18 11:17:05.155 MSK 10304 127.0.0.1(38834)LOG:  duration: 0.086 ms  statement: SHOW default_transaction_isolation
[LOG ENTRY] 2013-09-18 11:17:05.158 MSK 10304 127.0.0.1(38834)LOG:  duration: 0.804 ms  statement: SELECT ...
[LOG ENTRY] 2013-09-18 11:17:05.164 MSK 10304 127.0.0.1(38834)LOG:  duration: 0.092 ms  statement: SHOW default_transaction_isolation
[LOG ENTRY] 2013-09-18 11:17:05.168 MSK 10304 127.0.0.1(38834)LOG:  duration: 0.757 ms  statement: SELECT ...
[LOG ENTRY] 2013-09-18 11:17:05.175 MSK 10304 127.0.0.1(38834)LOG:  duration: 0.085 ms  statement: SHOW default_transaction_isolation
[LOG ENTRY] 2013-09-18 11:17:05.178 MSK 10304 127.0.0.1(38834)LOG:  duration: 0.779 ms  statement: SELECT ...
[LOG ENTRY] 2013-09-18 11:17:05.185 MSK 10304 127.0.0.1(38834)LOG:  duration: 0.091 ms  statement: SHOW default_transaction_isolation
[LOG ENTRY] 2013-09-18 11:17:05.190 MSK 10304 127.0.0.1(38834)LOG:  duration: 1.492 ms  statement: SELECT ...
[LOG ENTRY] 2013-09-18 11:17:05.197 MSK 10304 127.0.0.1(38834)LOG:  duration: 0.090 ms  statement: SHOW default_transaction_isolation
```

There is a `SHOW default_transaction_isolation` query after my target query. Log says that it takes 0.086 ms to perform this strange query, but it creates about 10 ms delays around it:

- query #1 finished 11:17:05.148
- strange query
- query #2 finished 11:17:05.158

Does anybody know whether this is a bug of django, psycopg, postgres or any other app? How can I investigate this?

**UPD** Pure Django project (only Django, postgresql, psycopg2) executes queries without that bug. Maybe there is something in project's apps or third-party apps. I'm trying to investigate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It took me several days to discover the source of the problem. It took so much time because of my wrong guesses: I was sure the problem was caused somehow by database or database-python connection library.

The reason was **django-debug-toolbar** - as I understand, its measurement of SQL execution time causes poor performance in general.

As a summary, if your Django site is slow - check whether `DEBUG = False` and `django-debug-toolbar` is switched off.

Comment: Still valid in 2020. I made the same experience and wondered why it took forever to load my page. After I deactivated django-debug-toolbar, it rendered instantly again. Thank you!